# Snowflake PROCEDURES: Create Schemas Based on a Column in a Table

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

1. Run **SHOW SCHEMAS IN DATABASE D_DATAVAULT** to get the list of all available schemas in D_DATAVAULT
2. PUT the **name** column in an vector or a list
3. Loop the **CREATE SCHEMA  CLONE**  using the vector or list

[VISUAL AID FOR ITEMS 1-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WPPq.png)

P.S. Cloning the database is not applicable to us. We want to preserve the ownership/priv of the schemas.

The output should be schemas being created in the new database.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this effect by using Snowflake Scripting:

- [SCHEMATA View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/schemata)
- [Cursor-Based FOR Loops](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops#label-snowscript-loop-for-cursor)
- [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate)

Main block:

```
DECLARE
   sql TEXT;
   
   schema_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT SCHEMA_NAME
        FROM D_DATAVAULT.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
        WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('PUBLIC', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA');
BEGIN
   FOR record IN schema_cursor DO
     sql := REPLACE('CREATE SCHEMA TARGET.<schema> CLONE D_DATAVAULT.<schema>'
                    , '<schema>', record.schema_name);
                    
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql;
   END FOR;
END;
```

Input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE D_DATAVAULT;
CREATE SCHEMA SCH_A;
CREATE SCHEMA SCH_B;
CREATE SCHEMA SCH_C;

CREATE DATABASE TARGET;
-- no user defined schemas
```

Output:

```
SHOW SCHEMAS IN DATABASE TARGET;
-- INFORMATION_SCHEMA
-- PUBLIC
-- SCH_A
-- SCH_B
-- SCH_C
```